# Input string was not in a correct format error in MySQL query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-update, query-string

Hi I am working on an application which works with MySQL database and C# 4.0.

I have below method to update a MySQL table. But while executing the below method I am getting error that `Input string was not in a correct format.`

Method call:

```
UpdateOnline(mcon, convertedXml, fileName, stmId);
```

Method definition:

```
private void UpdateOnline(MySqlConnection mcon, string convertedXml, string fileName,int stmtId)
    {
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand("update user_account_statement set statement_xml=@xml,"+
            " file_name=@fName, status='closed' where statement_id=@stmtId",mcon);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xml", MySqlDbType.LongText).Value = convertedXml;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fileName;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stmtId", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value=stmtId;
        var query = cmd.ToString();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

I checked many times for data types and all but not able to figure it out that where I am missing.

**UPDATE**

Table schema is below:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_account_statement` (
`statement_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`statement_xml` longtext NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`file_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`statement_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1084 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Are you sure your column types are right? Did you debug your code? What are the value of your parameters? You didn't use `convertedStmt` and `query` anywhere in your code. And change your `@fName` to `@fileName`

Comment: @SonerGönül I have updated the table schema and code. please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked for me. :

```
 private void UpdateOnline(MySqlConnection mcon, string convertedXml, MemoryStream statment, string fileName, int stmtId)
    {
        var convertedStmt = statment.ToArray();
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand("update user_account_statement set" +
         " file_name=@fName,statement_file=@stmt, statement_xml=@xml, status='closed' where statement_id=@stmtId", mcon);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fName", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@stmtId", MySqlDbType.UInt32);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@xml", MySqlDbType.LongText);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@stmt", MySqlDbType.LongBlob);
        cmd.Parameters["@fName"].Value = fileName;
        cmd.Parameters["@stmtId"].Value = stmtId;
        cmd.Parameters["@xml"].Value = convertedXml;
        cmd.Parameters["@stmt"].Value = convertedStmt;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at your parameters bud . . 
in your query string it says, @xml, @fName, @stmtId

then the lines with AddWithValue, your code says @xml, @fileName, @stmtId

Comment: how about trying this instead

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xml", convertedXml);`

just do the same with the other 2